# Python create an xml file for every row in excel

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I have the following code which creates a xml file from each row in excel. I want to write the xml files in a new folder (currently generates files in same folder as python), how do i change the "output.write()" statement? I am new in programming, started with python 2 weeks ago.

[wb_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5tI3.png)

df_data is a list of dictionaries.

```
[{'Nume': 'Ciuica', 'Prenume': 'Larisa Bianca', 'Data': '30/01/1991 00:00:00', 'Cod': 789454, 'Localitate': 'Targu Jiu'},
 {'Nume': 'Balasa', 'Prenume': 'Valentin', 'Data': '14/09/1989 00:00:00', 'Cod': 215487, 'Localitate': 'Bucuresti'},
 {'Nume': 'Vinatoru', 'Prenume': 'Costin', 'Data': '06/12/1980 00:00:00', 'Cod': 254896, 'Localitate': 'Titu'}]
```

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Et
import pandas as pd

wb_data = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_name="Data", header=0)
wb_xml = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_name="XML", header=0)

df_data = wb_data.to_dict("records")

lista_xml = []
index_lista = 0

for xml in wb_xml["Denumire_xml"]:
    lista_xml.append(xml)

for row in df_data:
    document = Et.Element("Document")
    for key, value in row.items():
        element = Et.SubElement(document, key)
        element.text = str(value)
    output = Et.ElementTree(document)
    Et.indent(output)
    output.write(lista_xml[index_lista])
    index_lista = index_lista + 1
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short, representative sample of `df_data` as well as the expected output from that sample?

Comment: I can't put pictures yet. Need to have 10.. something. It let me put a link which is wb_data. Edited with df_data, it is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: We absolutely do not want pictures of text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @tripleee that's not a picture of text.. it's the input excel. It'a a small table, the original data frame before the df_data = wb_data.to_dict("records"). The code works. I need a small change in it so that the 3 xml files to be in a new folder rather than same folder as python file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use absolute path especially with `os.path.join` to concatenate folder and file name:

```py
import os
...

xml_file_path = "/path/to/my/xml/outputs"

output.write(
    os.path.join(xml_file_path, lista_xml[index_lista])
)
```

However, consider the new [**`DataFrame.to_xml()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html) to export data frame rows to XML files:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

xml_file_path = "/path/to/my/xml/outputs"

wb_data = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_name="Data", header=0)
wb_xml = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_name="XML", header=0)

# LIST COMPREHENSION
lista_xml = [xml for xml in wb_xml["Denumire_xml"]]

# SERIES TO LIST CONVERSION
lista_xml = wb_xml["Denumire_xml"].tolist()

# GROUP BY INDEX (I.E., ROW) WITH LOOP NUMBER
for n, (i, sub_df) in enumerate(wb_data.groupby(level=0)):
    sub_df.to_xml(
        os.path.join(xml_file_path, lista_xml[n])
    )
```

Comment: HI @Parfait , Thank you for your answer. I tried the absolute path but i didn't manage to get it to work... I know my code isn't the optimal one... but like i said i'm only 2 weeks into python and i have a lot more ahead to understand. Your firs suggestion works perfect :D, although I will try to do it with **DataFrame.to_xml()** too